# Not getting result outside of nested query block in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, nodes

I have used `nested query` format it's work fine when I print `console.log(main_array)` in the **second** `db.query` section this will return parent_category and child category in single array like parent child relation but when I send whole data `outside of second query` section then this will return only `parent category` instead of whole data.

I have used following script in **nodeJs**.

```
learnAPI: (req, res) => {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM category where parent_id IS NULL";
    const main_array = {};
    var tets = {};
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
            let cat_name = result[key]['name'];
            main_array[cat_name] = result[key];
            let getsubcategory = "SELECT * FROM category where parent_id = " + result[key]['id'];
            db.query(getsubcategory, (err, subcategory) => {
                Object.keys(subcategory).forEach(function (key) {
                    let sub_name = subcategory[key]['name'];
                    main_array[cat_name][sub_name] = subcategory[key];
                });
                tets = main_array;
            });
            console.log(tets);
        });
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
        res.status(200).send(main_array);
    });
},
```

Anyone knows how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 learnAPI: (req, res) => {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM category where parent_id IS NULL";
    let main_array = {};
    let tets = [];
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
            let cat_name = result[key]['name'];
            main_array[cat_name] = result[key];
            let getsubcategory = "SELECT * FROM category where parent_id = " + result[key]['id'];
            db.query(getsubcategory, (err, subcategory) => {
                Object.keys(subcategory).forEach(function (key) {
                    let sub_name = subcategory[key]['name'];
                    main_array[cat_name][sub_name] = subcategory[key];
                });
                tets.push(main_array);
            });
            console.log(tets);
        });
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
        res.status(200).send(main_array);
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed my answer Please check

Comment: I have tried both ways but getting error " TypeError: db.query(...).then is not a functionType a message"

Comment: `const main_array = {};`
you defined main_array as const, change it to `var` OR `let`, because `const` can't be overwrite;

Comment: Using await function we are receive this object for second queryType a message https://ibb.co/Bf19kww

Comment: Same issue, it's return blank array.